# How to get function name and function arguments in JS eclipse template?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, templates, eclipse-templates

I have been trying to generate customised comments for JavaScript code in eclipse. For that I am using templates. I want to get following function name and arguments inside my comments.

Here is my template code:

```
/** @method [@public|@private|@protected] [return-type] ${enclosing_method} ${enclosing_method_arguments}
 * @brief
 * @param ${enclosing_method_arguments}
 * @retval ${return_type}
 */
```

Here is my Output when I try to generate template for a method:

```
/** @method [@public|@private|@protected] [return-type] enclosing_method enclosing_method_arguments
 * @brief
 * @param ${enclosing_method_arguments}
 * @retval ${return_type}
 */
 function sub(a,b){
    c=a+b;
    return c;
 }
```

Here is what I want:

```
/** @method [@public|@private|@protected] int sub(a,b)
 * @brief
 * @param a
 * @param b
 * @retval c
 */
 function sub(a,b){
    c=a+b;
    return c;
 }
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Thanks in advance.